# What causes vortices at the billiard ball particle level?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gas, molecular-dynamics, vortex

In a fluid/gas model consisting of billiard ball hard particle collisions what are the key behaviours that are needed to manifest the larger scale vortices?

I can only seem to find descriptions of vortices at the more macro continuum level.

Could it be something to do with a higher density of collisions towards the vortex centre?